# How do I initialize a webhook receiver in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webhooks, asp.net-routing

I'm following this guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks/receiving/receivers) for installing and using webhooks in ASP.Net MVC, but it looks like this guide is for a wep api type project. I'm using a MVC type project and there is no Register method, unlike a API project. In MVC we have a RegisterRoutes method. So how do I register my webhooks in MVC?

an API project that uses Register and config, my ASP.Net MVC site doesn't have this.

[image]

MVC uses RegisterRoutes

[image]

***UPdate***
Here I added a web api controller and the code I posted below is whats in the web api controller. I included the nuget packages for webhooks, the registration in global.asax.cs and in the register method. But I'm still having problems reaching the code 'ExecuteAsync' no breakpoints are being hit

```
public class StripeWebHookHandler : WebHookHandler
{
    // ngrok http -host-header="localhost:[port]" [port]
    // http(s)://<yourhost>/api/webhooks/incoming/stripe/   strip receiver

    public StripeWebHookHandler()
    {
        this.Receiver = StripeWebHookReceiver.ReceiverName;
    }

    public override Task ExecuteAsync(string generator, WebHookHandlerContext context)
    {
        // For more information about Stripe WebHook payloads, please see 
        // 'https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks'
        StripeEvent entry = context.GetDataOrDefault<StripeEvent>();

        // We can trace to see what is going on.
        Trace.WriteLine(entry.ToString());

        // Switch over the event types if you want to
        switch (entry.EventType)
        {
            default:
                // Information can be returned in a plain text response
                context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse();
                context.Response.Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Hello {0} event!", entry.EventType));
                break;
        }

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Going further, do not post images, post the code in the question.

Comment: hi did you make it work?

Answer (score 2):

You can mix web api controllers in your MVC project. When you add web api controllers, you will have a `WebApiConfig.cs` file in your App_Start where you will definie the routing for web api. That is where you can call the `InitializeReceiveStripeWebHooks` method after adding the necessary nuget packages to your project.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Load receivers
        config.InitializeReceiveStripeWebHooks();
    }
}
```

When you create a new project, Visual studio present you with different project templates. You can select the WebApi one which includes MVC and Web Api support. But if your project is created using the MVC template, it will not have the web api support by default. In that case, you can manually add it by following these steps.

**Step #1**

Create a new class called `WebApiConfig.cs` in the App_Start folder. Have the below content in that class

```
using System.Web.Http;
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Step #2**

Now go to global.asax and update the `Application_Start` event to include a call to the `Register` method in our newly created `WebApiConfig` class.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);  // This is the new line

    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Now you can right click on project and add new WebApiController classes and web api's should work now.

Comment: I added a web api controller to my MVC project but it didn't add a webapiconfig.cs file into my App_Start folder!!

Comment: Adding a detailed response to that in few minutes.

Comment: @user1186050 VS does not do that. So you have to manually do that. Just follow the two steps from the answer.

Comment: Hi. ok I did all this and added a new class on the web api controller to test. I'll update the code now. But I still can't hit any breakpoints inside the code. And I'm only seeing times out error messages in my Stripe dashboard. I see httppost requests coming in through ngrok (localhost:4040) and in the console screen where ngrok is running, but nothing seeks to be coming into the actual method 'ExecuteAsync' in the WEB Api class

Comment: Your question was not "how to make it work" , but where to add the call to enable it. For that i suggest you post a question specifically about that with relevant part of the code.